# What must I already know to get profound knowledge in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I've been working with relational database systems for about 4 years, 2 years in Oracle particularly. I've been able to do pretty much everything I've needed so far but I know that the knowledge I have in Oracle is like a drop of water in ocean. I'm sure that I'm not aware of or don't use many features that Oracle has or don't use them properly. To be short, I think my knowledge is not enough for professional database development/administration. So I've decided to learn Oracle real deep. I am interested in getting certificates but not as much as I want to learn it really well. Is there anything that I have to know in advance? I think there're quite a bit of things in Oracle that are the same in all RDBMS's, that is fundamental concepts. Any suggestions on useful course(s) or book(s) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Oracle Concepts manual from (virtual) cover to (virtual) cover.

The latest version is at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/toc.htm

If you know and understand all of this you'll be in the top 1% of all DBAs.

Comment: This is doubtful. Many concepts aren't that easy to grasp if you're using this guide solely. For example I couldn't get how indexes actually work–although this is what every DBA should understand–based only on Oracle guides until I found one of the posts like [this](http://www.orafaq.com/node/1403). I believe there are many guides which are far better than Oracle docs at explaining how things actually work–[Oracle Core: Essential Internals for DBAs and Developers](http://www.apress.com/9781430239543), to name one. Besides, I think the question is not constructive, and I'd vote to close it.

Comment: I'm assuming every computer programmer has an understanding of basic computer science topics. And a DBA is a computer programmer in my books. It's just a more declarative means of programming the computer. As far as an understanding of (B-tree) indexes goes, I find http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#sthref301 to be perfectly adequate, but terse.

Comment: Yea, but to be in the top 1% of all DBAs you need to go deeper (really deeper!) than just basic understanding.

Comment: I maintain that most DBAs don't understand all that's in the Oracle Concepts manual, let alone basic computer science topics such as complexity and algorithms.

Comment: As of this past December, Oracle certification (associate dba/dba) required attending the first and second Oracle admin classes (around $3500 each).  I recently have had to take on oracle (we purchased an app that only runs on it) and have had more issues to date with the utilities assoicated with it.  I read the oracle docs and then subscribe to safari.com for a different perspective.